# How can I delimitate a string at runtime?

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking to write a utility to batch rename a bunch of files at once using a regular expression. The files that I will be renaming all at once follow a certain naming convention, and I want to alter them to a new naming convention using data that's already in the filenames; but not all my files follow the same convention currently.

So I want to be able to write a general use program that lets me input into a textbox during runtime the pattern of the filename, and what tokens I want to extract from the filename to use for renaming.

For example - Assume I have one file named `[Coalgirls]_Suite_Precure_02_(1280x720_Blu-Ray_FLAC)_[33D74D55].mkv`. I want to be able to rename this file to `Suite Precure - Ep 02 [Coalgirls][33D74D55].mkv`

This means I would preferably be able to enter into my program before renaming something akin to `[%group%]_Suite_Precure_%ep%_(...)_[%crc%].mkv` and it would populate the local variables `group`, `ep`, and `crc` to use in the batch rename.

One particular program I'm thinking of that does this is mp3tag, used for converting file names to id3 tags. It lets you put something like %artist% - %album% - %tracknumber% - %title%, and it takes those 4 tokens and puts them into the respective id3 tags.

How can I make a system similar to this without having to make the user know regex syntax?

Comment: Always add examples of input and output. It makes 1000% clearer to udnerstand.

Comment: I see that you clarified your question after my answer. Was it not helpful?

Comment: @usr Your answer seemed at first glance to make it seem like I'd have to know the exact value of the CRC ahead of time to capture it. I may have been mistaken in reading it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by usr, you can extract all the named placeholders in the search string using `%(?<name>[^%]+)%`. This will get you "group", "ep", and "crc".

Now you need to scan all the fragments between the placeholders and put a capture at each placeholder in the regex. I'd iterate through the matches from above (you can get start offset and length of each match to navigate through the non-placeholder fragments).

(There are mistakes in your example, I'll assume the last part is correct and I'm dropping the mysterious (...))

It would build a regex that looks like this:

`^%(?<group>.*?)_Suite_Precure_(?<ep>.*?)_(?<crc>.*?).mkv$`

Pass the literal fragments to Regex.Escape before using it in the regex to handle troublesome characters properly.

Now, for each filename, you try to match the regex to it. If it matches, you get the values of the placeholders for this file. Then you take those placeholder values and merge them into the output pattern, replacing the placeholders appropriately. This gives you the new name, you can do the rename.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace renamer
{
    class RenameImpl
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>> RenameWithPatterns(
            string path, string curpattern, string newpattern,
            bool caseSensitive)
        {
            var placeholderNames = new List<string>();

            // Extract all the cur_placeholders from the user's input pattern
            var input_regex = new Regex(@"(\%[^%]+\%)");
            var cur_matches = input_regex.Matches(curpattern);
            var new_matches = input_regex.Matches(newpattern);
            var regex_pattern = new StringBuilder();

            if (!caseSensitive)
                regex_pattern.Append("(?i)");
            regex_pattern.Append('^');

            // Do a pass over the matches and grab info about each capture
            var cur_placeholders = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();
            var new_placeholders = new List<Tuple<string, int, int>>();
            for (var i = 0; i < cur_matches.Count; ++i)
            {
                var m = cur_matches[i];
                cur_placeholders.Add(new Tuple<string, int, int>(
                    m.Value, m.Index, m.Length));
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < new_matches.Count; ++i)
            {
                var m = new_matches[i];
                new_placeholders.Add(new Tuple<string, int, int>(
                    m.Value, m.Index, m.Length));
            }

            // Build the regular expression
            for (var i = 0; i < cur_placeholders.Count; ++i)
            {
                var ph = cur_placeholders[i];

                // Get the literal before the first capture if it is the first
                if (i == 0 && ph.Item2 > 0)
                    regex_pattern.Append(Regex.Escape(
                        curpattern.Substring(0, ph.Item2)));

                // Generate the capture for the placeholder
                regex_pattern.AppendFormat("(?<{0}>.*?)",
                    ph.Item1.Replace("%", ""));

                // The literal after the placeholder
                if (i + 1 == cur_placeholders.Count)
                    regex_pattern.Append(Regex.Escape(
                        curpattern.Substring(ph.Item2 + ph.Item3)));
                else
                    regex_pattern.Append(Regex.Escape(
                        curpattern.Substring(ph.Item2 + ph.Item3,
                        cur_placeholders[i + 1].Item2 - (ph.Item2 + ph.Item3))));
            }

            regex_pattern.Append('$');

            var re = new Regex(regex_pattern.ToString());

            foreach (var pathname in Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(path))
            {
                var file = Path.GetFileName(pathname);
                var m = re.Match(file);

                if (!m.Success)
                    continue;

                // New name is initially same as target pattern 
                var newname = newpattern;

                // Iterate through the placeholder names
                for (var i = new_placeholders.Count; i > 0; --i)
                {
                    // Target placeholder name
                    var tn = new_placeholders[i-1].Item1.Replace("%", "");

                    // Get captured value for this capture
                    var ct = m.Groups[tn].Value;

                    // Perform the replacement
                    newname = newname.Remove(new_placeholders[i - 1].Item2,
                        new_placeholders[i - 1].Item3);
                    newname = newname.Insert(new_placeholders[i - 1].Item2, ct);
                }

                newname = Path.Combine(path, newname);
                yield return new Tuple<string, string>(pathname, newname);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't helping much more than usr's response, but I think I see where the confusion may be. I want to make general use token placeholders like %group%, %ep%, etc... I don't want the user to have to use raw regex syntax. One particular program I'm thinking of that does this is mp3tag, used for converting the filenames to id3 tags. It lets you put something like %artist% - %album% - %tracknumber% - %title%, and it takes those 4 tokens and puts them into the respective id3 tags. How can I make a system similar to this without having to make the user know regex syntax?

Comment: The user doesn't have to know regex syntax. You are simply generating a regex from the placeholders [group] [crc] etc. and the literal pieces of text in between. For example [Album] - [Artist] - [Title].mp3 becomes [Title] ([Album], [Artist]).mp3. That is what the user would do. This would do the same thing: [A] - [B] - [C].mp3 becomes [C] ([A], [B]).mp3. Just generate a regex, replacing the user's placeholders with (?<name>.*?) and then regex matches will extract that part of the string and give it name "name" in the group array.

Comment: In my example, " - " and " - " and ".mp3" are the pieces of literal text, the regex match thing extracts what the current filename has in those parts.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an implementation that I whipped together to demonstrate the algorithm I suggested. I'm adding it to the answer.

Comment: If I had a curpattern "%songname%.mp3" and newpattern "the song is called %songname%.mp3" then it would transform the filenames as you specified. The names of the placeholders don't matter. The matching input is inserted into the output where the output pattern has that name.

Comment: Updated to fix a couple of bugs and add support for case insensitive operation.

Comment: @doug65536, your answer is very good. I had the same idea of build the regex from the "segments" but did not invest the time. I think this is what the OP needs. +1

Comment: @doug65536 That's very interesting - I was thinking you'd have to specify the placeholder names ahead of time, but apparantly not. I'll have to examine the code to make sure I understand what's going on, but I thank you very much for your gracious assistance with this.

Comment: My pleasure! Your question was easy enough to get done quickly, and difficult enough to be fun :)

Comment: It needs further work, such as merging the directory path and the new names back together and using fullpaths, and perhaps transform it to return an `IEnumerable<Tuple<string,string>>` containing the fullpath old and new name using `yield return new Tuple<string,string>(oldfullpath, newfullpath)` instead of the `Debug.Print`. This way, you could `foreach` it to display what it's going to do in the UI, then have another code path that actually does the rename, both based on a `foreach` of the return value.

Comment: I updated the posted code to include the changes mentioned in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Make the regex pattern `%(?<name>[^%]+)%`. This will capture you all tokens in the string that are surrounded by percent signs.

Then, use `Regex.Replace` to replace them:

```
var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, (Match m) => EvaluateToken(m.Groups["name"].Value));
```

`Regex.Replace` can take a callback that allows you to provide a dynamic value.

Comment: This sounds like it will only work on values that I already know specifically exist... Will this allow me to capture various different CRC values in different filenames? See the example I edited into the original post...

Comment: Now I understand. Can't you just have the user enter a regex that will capture the values of interest (like CRC) into named groups?

Comment: The problem is, I want to feed in a multitude of files to be batch renamed as per this pattern. I may have 24 or more filenames fitting the original pattern so I want them to be all renamed properly at once.